# How to structure a database design for a simple photo album in couchdb?

Tags: database-design, nosql, couchdb

I want to try CouchDb by developping a little PhotoAlbum application where different users can have many albums with many photos in them. Am i doing it right if I create a document for each users, that contains an array of albums, that contains photos with attachments?

```
{ 
    user: "Dominik", 
    albums: [ 
        { name: "USA Trip", photos: 
            [ 
                { title: "Golden Gate Bridge", _attachments: [ the photo ] },
                { another photo } 
            ]
        },
        { ...} ] 
}
```

or is there another good way to do this?

or is it better to store users, albums and photos each in different documents? This would require foreign keys as in mysql?

```
{ type: "user", name: "Dominik", albums: [ "a1", "a2", "a3" ] }
{ type: "album", _id: "a1", title: "USA Trip", photos: [ "p1", "p2" ... ] }
{ type: "photo", _id: "p1", _attachments: {...}, title: "Golden Gate Bridge" }
```

...

or the other way around?:

```
{ type: "user", _id: "u1", name: "Dominik" }
{ type: "album", _id: "a1", title: "USA Trip", user: "u1" }
{ type: "photo", _id: "p1", _attachments: {...}, title: "Golden Gate Bridge", album: "a1" }
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view it's better to divide your data into small portions of it. But this is only your choice. i chose dividing because i was faced with memcached-server limit of 1Mb per "key-value-instance" (we cache CouchDB documents in memcached), so we couldn't store our data in one document.

But of course there are advantages of storing your data in one document. I hope other people will tell about their experience and you will choose what fits you best.

Comment: i forgot to tell about one more advantage of storing portions of data separately: if you change one of your photos' title in your album, the whole document will update (and ETag too), which is often not very good.

Answer (score 1):

1999 is right. Two more minor points:

1. Remember, **Apache CouchDB supports atomic transactions**—but only within a document. You can change anything in a document with a single atomic operation.
2. *In the CouchDB security framework*, your security policy is applied one document at at time, in isolation. The `validate_doc_update` function cannot see foreign documents when it has to decide what a user may do. (If you do not use CouchDB for accounts and authentication, this is not relevant.)